# Should I use "on" or "over" with these sentences?

Tags: prepositions

Should I use "on" or "over" with these sentences and what is the difference?

- > you should not be jealous when others succeed on you.
- > you should not be jealous when others succeed over you.

Comment: I would actually recommend picking a different word other than "succeed".  This isn't really an idiomatic way of phrasing this thought.

Comment: "when others succeed more than you do" is a possible alternatve.

Comment: Are you trying to say that one person has attained more success than another, or that one person defeated another in a head-to-head competition?

Answer (score 1):

> you should not be jealous when others succeed over you.

*Succeed over X* where X is a person and not a non-personal obstacle strikes me as a native speaker as not commonly heard, but your message comes through here.  You are saying you should not be jealous when someone succeeds more than you or instead of you.  You're using *over* correctly here, although in a less than common way.

In a very formal or professional setting you should stick to common patterns ("you should not be jealous when others succeed more than you" as suggested in comments") to ensure maximum clarity.

> you should not be jealous when others succeed on you.

This doesn't make sense.  *X on Y* means X is above Y and usually attached to or touching Y as well.  *On* is also part of numerous phrasal verbs, but *succeed* isn't one of them.

Answer (score 1):

Neither of these sentences are natural English.  Some more natural examples of what you might be trying to say:

> You should not be jealous if others have more success than you.
>
> You should not be jealous if others are more successful than you.
>
> You should not be jealous if others achieve success when/while you do not.
>
> You should not be jealous if others are promoted above you.
>
> You should not be jealous if others are promoted more quickly than you.